# Serving CSS and JS in single files, possible advantanges and drawbacks

Tags: php, javascript, css, apache, compression

I noticed some time ago that many big sites sometimes serve their CSS and JS files in a surprisingly small number (even one single file) and with strange alphanumeric names. What I thought was that these filenames were hashes, which in turn lead me to suspect that:

- They were cached
- They were dynamically created to reduce the amount of HTTP overheads from various CSS and JS "bits"

Some internet research showed me that I was right and this approach is somewhat existent and valued, and I would like to implement it in a WAMP/LAMP site I'm developing - a site that, for its modular plugin structure, serves often a lot of tiny and medium-sized CSS and JS files.

---

These are my questions:

1. how can I update the cache automatically on file update? The solution I came up with was to create a sort of "signature string" for every page, joining the file paths AND the last modification time, then hash the signature with MD5 and feed it to the cache to determine if the hash/filename is existent. Is it a correct approach? any drawbacks?
2. the next logical step would be **minification**. Minifying CSS files is rather simple; is JS minification reliable too? Any good class out on the internet?
3. another problem: what about already minified scripts? The only solution aside some form of parsing I thought of was to compare size before and after minification, if size after < size before then use the PHP-minified form. Computational overhead should be solved by caching, right?
4. **The most important issue**: **CSS images**. Here I *really* don't have a clue: collecting various CSS in different places *breaks all the relative image links*. I cannot use absolute paths (break site relocability). I'd prefer not using a standard directory structure for CSS images (f.ex. placing all CSS referenced images under a `css/img` dir) because of potential filename conflicts. This would mean also parsing the CSS in some way. How can I solve this?
5. Compression: do I have to implement always a software PHP based GZIP compression, or (very ignorant in that field) can it be enforced automatically on an Apache server?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Please stick to one question per question, and search first. Quite a lot of these are duplicates.

Comment: @Quentin: do you think I'd better break up the questions? I thought that the argument (CSS/JS serving with PHP caching and compression) was unique, and I've seen other questions (often very upvoted) posed with many points like mine. Any opinion appreciated though :)

Comment: on 5.) id recommend putting them in one folder,its much easier to find and if you have problems with filename conflicts, put them inside folders within the img folder

Comment: @ianace I assume you are answring for point 4: actually, I've found an incredible useful class from Dmytro Kadyrov's answer: [http://code.google.com/p/minify/source/browse/min/lib/Minify/CSS/UriRewriter.php]

Comment: @Cranio kindly update your url there's an extra `]` to the end of it :D, and by the way cool link

Comment: @ianace I've tried but I cannot edit my own comments... don't know why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I using is a very good library https://github.com/mrclay/minify for this. Its library automaticaly minify css and js files into one file and rebuild cache on modification files.

Comment: Seems interesting, many thanks. Does it also address the CSS image problem?

Comment: YES IT DOES! I'm taking the code from a particular class [http://code.google.com/p/minify/source/browse/min/lib/Minify/CSS/UriRewriter.php] it integrates perfectly with my code and solves my main concern! Thank you!

Comment: what is the CSS image problem?